# Filename while downloading in Safari comes to be 'untitled'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file, download, safari

I have implemented the following code which downloads the file in Safari but the filename comes to be 'untitled'. In other browsers it works good.

```
var saveData = (function () {
var base64 = "data:application/msword;base64,iVBOR---<some data>---JoU8gAAAAASUVORK5CYII=";
                            var uri = encodeURI(base64);
                                var anchor = document.createElement('a');
                                document.body.appendChild(anchor);
                                anchor.href = uri;
                                anchor.download = "hello";


                    anchor.click();
                                        document.body.removeChild(anchor);
}());
    saveData();
```

This is the link to the JSFiddle to get this tested. [JSFiddle_here](https://jsfiddle.net/cW7W5/1943/)

Answer (score 0):

`anchor.download = "hello";`

Make sure your version of safari is 10.1 or above as download attribute is supported for safari from 10.1 only as show in this [link](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download)

**EDIT:**

You can use [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) which has support for good number of browsers.

Comment: He said that its working but only the filename is "untitled". Iam sure he know about the support of the attribute "download" in safari.

Comment: Yes, download of the content is working fine however the filename is 'unknown'. And I had used FileSaver as well. I did not work well in Safari.

Comment: I am running safari 15.1 and even after setting download I still get a file name "unkown".
Same problem with FileSaver.js (only difference is that one saves it as unkown.txt and one saves it without extension)